# Papers on anger detection in dialogues

Tags: nlp, lstm, cnn

I am interested in anger detection in dialogues and I want to study multiple methods like LSTM, CNN, etc. Are there any good research papers or books about this subject?

Answer (score 2):

DeepMoji is a fun project that came out of MIT, which predicts emojis that are most related to an input sentence. Gimmicks aside, it seems perfectly adequate for your task of anger detection.

- [Paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00524)
- [Blog post](https://medium.com/@bjarkefelbo/what-can-we-learn-from-emojis-6beb165a5ea0)
- Pretrained models: [PyTorch](https://github.com/huggingface/torchMoji) or [Keras](https://github.com/bfelbo/DeepMoji).